# $A_{\infty}$ singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

What kind of singularity is commonly meant by $A_{\infty}$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14489/limit-of-a-series-of-singularities

Comment: It would help if you said what type of singularity you think $A_n$ means; Fly by Night's answer below is using a different notion of $A_n$ than the question Francesco links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\mu \ge 0,$ the $A_{\mu}$ series of map germs $f : (\mathbb{R}^n,0) \to (\mathbb{R},0)$ is, for $\varepsilon_i = \pm 1$, given by $f(x) = \varepsilon_1x_1^2 + \cdots + \varepsilon_{n-1}x_{n-1}^2 \pm x_n^{\mu +1}$. These all have algebraically isolated singularities at $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I this setting, finite Milnor number is equivalent to the singularity being isolated. For $\mu = \infty$, the $A_{\infty}$ singularity is non-isolated, and is given by $f(x) = \varepsilon_1x_1^2 + \cdots + \varepsilon_{n-1}x_{n-1}^2$. Notice the lack of $x_n$. If you're working over $\mathbb{C}$ then drop all of the $\pm$s.

Comment: @David: They're the same notation. In Francesco's link $n = 2$ and we get the $A_{\mu}$ series given by $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^{\mu+1}$, with $A_{\infty}$ being $f(x) = x_1^2$.